# Mapbox map with plotly in jupyter not showing up

Tags: jupyter-notebook, mapbox, plotly

I am using plotly in a Jupyter notebook (python v3.6) and trying to get the example code for mapbox to work (see: https://plot.ly/python/scattermapbox/).

When I execute the cell, I don't get any error, but I see no output either, just a blank output cell.  When I mouse over the output cell area, I can see there's a frame there, and I even see the plotly icon tray at the top right, but there doesn't seem to be anything else.  When I hit the 'edit chart' button at the bottom right, I get taken to the plotly page with a blank canvas.
As far as I can tell, my mapbox api token is valid.

My code looks identical to the example linked above:

```
data = Data([
    Scattermapbox(
        lat=['45.5017'],
        lon=['-73.5673'],
        mode='markers',
        marker=Marker(
            size=14
        ),
        text=['Montreal'],
    )
])

layout = Layout(
    autosize=True,
    hovermode='closest',
    mapbox=dict(
        accesstoken=mapbox_token,
        bearing=0,
        center=dict(
            lat=45,
            lon=-73
        ),
        pitch=0,
        zoom=1,
        style='light'
    ),
)

fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout)
py.iplot(fig)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thx!

Answer (score 3):

D'oh!  Was using the wrong mapbox token.  I should have used the public token, but instead used a private one.  The only error was a js one in the console.
Thanks user1561393!

```
jupyter labextension install plotlywidget
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your `mapbox_token`? My guess is you haven't signed up for Mapbox to get an API token (which allows you to download their excellent tile maps for mapbox-gl). The map's not going to show without this token.

Comment: As I mentioned above, I did indeed sign up for mapbox and my token is valid.  So it's not that.

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser console that look like they could be related?

Comment: nope, no errors.  When I execute the cell, I even see the animated plotly bars dancing around for a second or 2, but when they disappear, nothing shows up in their place.